# Service not known when writing to InfluxDB in Python

Tags: python, docker, influxdb

I'm using Docker with InfluxDB and Python in a framework. I want to write to InfluxDB inside the framework but I always get the error "Name or service not known" and have no idea what is the problem.

I link the InfluxDB container to the framework container in the docker compose file like so:

```
version: '3'
  services:
    influxdb:
      image: influxdb
      container_name: influxdb
      restart: always
      ports:
        - 8086:8086
      volumes:
        - influxdb_data:/var/lib/influxdb

    framework:
      image: framework
      build: framework
      volumes:
        - framework:/tmp/framework_data
      links:
        - influxdb
      depends_on:
        - influxdb

 volumes:      
    framework:
      driver: local
    influxdb_data:
```

Inside the framework I have a script that only focuses on writing to the database. Because I don't want to access the database with the url "localhost:8086", I am using links to make it easier and connect to the database with the url "influxdb:8086". This is my code in that script:

```
from influxdb_client import InfluxDBClient, Point
from influxdb_client.client.write_api import SYNCHRONOUS, WritePrecision

bucket = "bucket"
token = "token"

def insert_data(message):  
    client = InfluxDBClient(url="http://influxdb:8086", token=token, org=org)
    write_api = client.write_api(write_options=SYNCHRONOUS)

    point = Point("mem") \
        .tag("sensor", message["sensor"]) \
        .tag("metric", message["type"]) \
        .field("true_value", float(message["true_value"])) \
        .field("value", float(message["value"])) \
        .field("failure", message["failure"]) \
        .field("failure_type", message["failure_type"]) \
        .time(datetime.datetime.now(), WritePrecision.NS)

    write_api.write(bucket, org, point)  #the error seams to happen here
```

Everytime I use the function `insert_data` I get the error `urllib3.exceptions.NewConnectionError: <urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x7fac547d9d00>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno -2] Name or service not known`.

Why can't I write into the database?

Comment: That's a DNS error.  It cannot resolve the network name `influxdb`  I'd take a look at your container configuration and make sure the hostname of your influxDB container is correctly set.  Then take a look at both container's network settings and make sure they are on the same docker network

Comment: @Rowshi could it be that the influxdb container isn't ready to access when the depends_on on the framework container is deployed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem resides in your docker-compose file. First of all `links` is a legacy feature so I'd recommend you to use user-defined networks instead. More on that here: https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v3/#links

I've created a minimalistic example to demonstrate the approach:

```
version: '3'
services:
  influxdb:
    image: influxdb
    container_name: influxdb
    restart: always
    environment: # manage the secrets the best way you can!!! the below are only for demonstration purposes...
      - DOCKER_INFLUXDB_INIT_USERNAME=admin
      - DOCKER_INFLUXDB_INIT_PASSWORD=secret
      - DOCKER_INFLUXDB_INIT_ORG=my-org
      - DOCKER_INFLUXDB_INIT_BUCKET=my-bucket
      - DOCKER_INFLUXDB_INIT_ADMIN_TOKEN=secret-token
    networks: 
      - local

  framework:
    image: python:3.10.2
    depends_on:
      - influxdb
    networks:
      - local

networks:
  local:
```

Notice the additional `networks` definition and the `local` network. Also this network is referenced from the containers.

Also make sure to initialize your influxdb with the right enviroment variables according to the docker image's documentation: https://hub.docker.com/_/influxdb

Then to test it just run a shell in your `framework` container via docker-compose:

`docker-compose run --entrypoint sh framework`

and then in the container install the client:

`pip install influxdb_client['ciso']`

Then in a python shell - still inside the container - you can verify the connection:

```py
from influxdb_client import InfluxDBClient
client = InfluxDBClient(url="http://influxdb:8086", token="secret-token", org="my-org")  # the token and the org values are coming from the container's docker-compose environment definitions
client.health()
# {'checks': [],
# 'commit': '657e1839de',
# 'message': 'ready for queries and writes',
# 'name': 'influxdb',
# 'status': 'pass',
# 'version': '2.1.1'}
```

Last but not least to clean up the test resources do:

`docker-compose down`

Comment: The error still persists unfortunately. When I run the curl command I get Could not resolve host: influxdb

Comment: Nevermind, just changed the network name and the curl command gives me that response. however, when I run the container I still get the Service not known error

Comment: Oh yeah, then I guess your influxdb container settings are wrong as well. Let me adjust it.